# ReactJS Element focus() not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a number input field that I'm trying to focus on after receiving input from a bar-code scanner. *In reality the scanner is just a pseudo keyboard that I watch for the tab key to get pressed.*

In Edge the input receives focus as expected, but in all other browsers tested (Chrome/Firefox) the input doesn't gain focus. Safari has not been testes since I'm on a PC.

```
// I'm using a lifecycle method to watch for a change to the components props. 
// The onInputFocused will unset the value, but I've disabled to this 
// to eliminate any possible race cases?!

componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.detail.shouldFocus) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.qtyInput.focus();
        }, 250);
        //     this.props.onInputFocused(this.props.detail);
    }
}
render(){
    return (
        ...
        <input type="number" className="form-control" min="0" name="qty_received" value={detail.ReceiptQuantityReceived}
                        ref={(input) => { this.qtyInput = input }}
                        onChange={(e) => { onQtyReceivedChange(e, detail) }}
                        onBlur={() => { onReceiveShipmentRowBlur(detail) }} />
    );
}
```

I originally was calling `focus` without a `setTimeout`, but attempted the timeout based on some suggestions online. I have also attempted to change the input to `text`, but that didn't have any effect either.

Doing a `console.log` on `this.qtyInput` outputs the expected element.

The only other thing I can think of is that the modal that a user scans in to gains it's focus via a similar function, but it has been removed by the time the focus call should be happening.

To add to the weirdness, I've added a `console.log` to the input's `onBlue` event and it is getting fired even though you can't type in the field or have any visual indication of focus.

Comment: I think you must try this.qtyInput.focus(); in componentDidMount() without a setTimeout.

Comment: In this case try debugging if this.props.detail.shouldFocus is true or not, because till now your focus is conditional on the value of this prop

Comment: The input should not have focus when rendered (ever) since the element will ALWAYS exist when the triggering element (the input field for the scanner) fires the state change. The state is applying as and when expected. The `focus()` just isn't getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you must try is add this attribute for your INPUT element
 (input autoFocus ..) 
this attribute may help you

Comment: This will apply focus when the element is rendered. I need focus applied programmatically based on the input of another element.